# JS - Get the correct element between two with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next piece of html code, and I'd like to get the second div with ajaxresponse_1 id, using JQuery, it'd be easy if I could add id atribute to it, but I cant. When I use $("#ajaxresponse_1") and append anyone element to it, it does not work. Can anyone help me?

```
<div id="ajaxresponse_1" class="ajaxresponse ajaxresponse_1" style="display: block;">
    <div id="ajaxresponse_1" class="ajaxresponse ajaxresponse_1">
        <h3 class="avia-form-success">O valor do IPVA é R$ 1500</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you change the HTML? You shouldn't have two elements with the same ID.

Comment: The worst is that I cant do that, because is a wordpress theme code :(

Answer (score 1):

Please use `find function` it will help you get the second div,you can also use `children function`.As suggested by @Steve you should not have multiple elements having the same ID

```
$("#ajaxresponse_1").find("div#ajaxresponse_1")
```